# Optimize Aggregate Query

Tags: mysql

Following is my aggregate query which takes 1.1sec. This query has multiple joins. Index on which columns will optimize the query.

```
         EXPLAIN SELECT straight_join
          aggsm.tdm_id AS topid,              
          sum(aggsm.m_count) AS mencnt ,
          sum(aggsm.ps_count) AS pscnt,
          sum(aggsm.ns_count) AS ngscnt,
          topdm.topic_name AS topname
         FROM AGG_MENTION AS aggsm 
         JOIN TOPICDM AS topdm  ON aggsm.topicdm_id = topdm.topicdm_id
         JOIN LOCATIONDM AS locdm ON aggsm.locationdm_id = locdm.locationdm_id
         JOIN CITY AS citydm ON locdm.city_id = citydm.city_id
         JOIN STATE AS statedm ON citydm.state_id = statedm.state_id
         WHERE aggsm.cdm_id = 11
         AND aggsm.ei_type IN (1,2,3,4)
         AND aggsm.datedm_id BETWEEN 20130101 AND 20130522   
         AND statedm.country_id IN (1,2,3,4) 
         AND topdm.topic_group_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)    
         GROUP BY aggsm.topicdm_id
         -- ORDER BY aggsm.topicdm_id DESC,sum(aggsm.m_count) DESC
         LIMIT 0,200000
```

Following is the explain output :

```
   1    SIMPLE  aggsm   ref PRIMARY,datedm_id_UNIQUE,agg_sm_locdm_fk_idx,agg_sm_comdm_fk_idx,agg_sm_topdm_fk_idx,agg_sm_datedm_fk_idx,agg_em_indtype_fk_idx,comp_top_dt,l_idx   comp_top_dt 8   const   202129  Using where; Using index
   1    SIMPLE  topdm   eq_ref  PRIMARY,topicdm_id_UNIQUE,topdm_grp_id_idx,id_idx   PRIMARY 8   opinionleaders.aggsm.topicdm_id 1   Using where
   1    SIMPLE  locdm   eq_ref  PRIMARY,city_id_UNIQUE,locationdm_id_UNIQUE,loc_city_fk_idx,id_idx  PRIMARY 8   opinionleaders.aggsm.locationdm_id  1   
   1    SIMPLE  citydm  eq_ref  PRIMARY,city_id_UNIQUE,city_state_fk_idx,id_idx PRIMARY 8   opinionleaders.locdm.city_id    1   
   1    SIMPLE  statedm eq_ref  PRIMARY,state_id_UNIQUE,state_country_fk_idx,id_idx PRIMARY 8   opinionleaders.citydm.state_id  1   Using where
```

Uncommenting the order by clause will cause aggsm table to use 'using temporary,using filesort'

How can we optimize the query or define index

Comment: Some ideas... Don't know if these will make it any better - just trying to help though :) 1) if possible split this massive query (for example with php) to smaller parts. 2) try to make result smaller to reserve memory; topic name may make it quite big or consider paging the result 3) check your mysql configuration and raise the limits depending on the engine you use

Comment: 1.1 seems quite good to me :-(. Still, do you have an index defined across (cdm_id,ei_type,datedm_id)?

Answer (score 0):

1) LIMIT 0,200000 is definitely not a good solution , i can barely see an aplication where you need such large amount of data, split it into chunks

2) in ORDER BY clause, you are specifying and sum(aggsm.m_count) -
this is an aggregate function , try addressing it as mencnt ( therefore ORDER BY aggsm.topicdm_id DESC,mencnt DESC ),not sure if SQL server understands it as you want

Answer (score 0):

slightly reformatted query for readability and seeing relationships and associated columns for index considerations. Since your Aggsm table is being grouped by the topicdm_id, I would at least try to get a covering index with this and the columns to get to your joined tables so it does not need to get to the raw page data until it has a qualified record to work with.  Also, include the components for your where clause.  I would suggest an index on the tables to have

```
table        index
agg_mention  ( cdm_id, ei_type, datedm_id, topicdm_id, locationdm_id )
topicdm      ( topicdm_id, topic_group_id )
state        ( state_id, country_id )
locationdm   ( locationdm_id )
city         ( city_id )

SELECT straight_join
      aggsm.tdm_id AS topid,
      sum(aggsm.m_count) AS mencnt,
      sum(aggsm.ps_count) AS pscnt,
      sum(aggsm.ns_count) AS ngscnt,
      topdm.topic_name AS topname
   FROM 
      AGG_MENTION AS aggsm 
         JOIN TOPICDM AS topdm  
            ON aggsm.topicdm_id = topdm.topicdm_id
            AND topdm.topic_group_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)    
         JOIN LOCATIONDM AS locdm 
            ON aggsm.locationdm_id = locdm.locationdm_id
            JOIN CITY AS citydm 
               ON locdm.city_id = citydm.city_id
               JOIN STATE AS statedm 
                  ON citydm.state_id = statedm.state_id
                  AND statedm.country_id IN (1,2,3,4) 
   WHERE 
          aggsm.cdm_id = 11
      AND aggsm.ei_type IN (1,2,3,4)
      AND aggsm.datedm_id BETWEEN 20130101 AND 20130522   
   GROUP BY 
      aggsm.topicdm_id
   ORDER BY 
      aggsm.topicdm_id DESC,
      sum(aggsm.m_count) DESC
   LIMIT 
      0,200000
```